# Accumulate algorithm incorrect sum

Tags: c++

Just began learning about algorithms in c++. My book mentions a simple read-only algorithm defined in the numeric header. It takes three parameters, the first are iterators that specify a range or elements to sum and the third is the initial value of the summation. However when i try to do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

int main() {

vector<int> numbers;

//Fill vector with numbers.
for (vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i != 10; i++) {
    numbers.push_back(i);
}

int sum = accumulate(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 1);
cout << numbers.size() << endl;
cout << sum << endl;

system("PAUSE");

return 0;
}
```

I get an output of: 10, 46. How can 10 plus 1 be 46? I can't see my error here, thanks for insight.

Comment: 10 plus 1 doesn't equal 46. And that's not what you're adding.

Comment: If you want to add 10 and 1, there's a simpler method: `int sum = 10 + 1;`.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Even simpler is to assign **11** to `sum` :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/numeric/accumulate/

Your vector has elements 0-9 inside whose sum is 45. As an offset to your accumulator you add 1. Therefore you get the correct result 46.

Answer (score 6):

You understood the algorithm incorrectly. std::accumulate results the sum of elements. Now, vector has 0-9 numbers. So, sum of 0-9 numbers is 45 and adding 1 ( third parameter passed to the algorithm is 1 in your case ) to it results 46.

Comment: yea i thought it was summing the number of elements not the cumulative value.